# mysql syntax for CASE 'NOT NULL' when used within SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use CASE `'NOT NULL'` within a `SELECT` statement but I keeping getting this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

```
SELECT 
        u.id,
                CASE  ph.thumbsize WHEN NULL THEN ph.thumbsize ELSE 'defaultpicture.jpg'

            FROM
            user u  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                list_photos ph
        ON 
                u.id = ph.userId;
```

I have also tried these different formats for `CASE`:

```
(CASE WHEN ph.thumbsize IS NOT NULL THEN 'ph.thumbsize' ELSE
 'defaultpicture.jpg')as picture       

           CASE WHEN ph.thumbsize IS NOT NULL THEN ph.thumbsize ELSE defaultpicture.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `END`, among other minor issues. Try:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    CASE WHEN (ph.thumbsize IS NULL) THEN 
        'defaultpicture.jpg'
    ELSE
        ph.thumbsize
    END AS picture
FROM
    user u  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    list_photos ph
ON 
    u.id = ph.userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
            CASE  ph.thumbsize WHEN NULL THEN ph.thumbsize ELSE 'defaultpicture.jpg' END

        FROM
        user u  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            list_photos ph
    ON 
            u.id = ph.userId;
```

In CASE you need to close it by END

Comment: `END CASE` is for [CASE statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html), not for [CASE expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case), as used here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [IFNULL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) :

..., IFNULL(ph.thumbsize,'defaultpicture.jpg') AS picture, ...

Comment: Hey Fabien. is this quicker than case?

Comment: There is no sigificant difference between both. Just more easy to code. Or you can use `COALESCE` in the same way. `COALESCE` is internally convert to a `CASE` statement